# How to know if an OutputStream can continue writing in Java?

Tags: java, outputstream

How to know if an `OutputStream` can continue writing in Java?

For `InputStream`, we can check whether `return` equals `-1` to know if the input stream has ended, but how do I check for `OutputStream`?

---

Why do I ask this question? For example, I need to write data into a byte array or a buffer, but the methods provided by the API only have parameters of `OutputStream` type. How can I make my `OutputStream` implementation tell the API that the array/buffer has been full?

Comment: What kind of stream are you writing to? Generally you can output as many bytes as you want.

Comment: What is your motivation for asking?

Comment: If an output stream is closed, it will throw an exception. Otherwise, you can assume you can continue to write.

Comment: @marcinj That is about sockets.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel right, that was wrong link. OutputStream implementation should throw exception if stream is closed, or any timeout for it is over (if it allows for timeouts).

Comment: By definition, an InputStream reaches its end when there is no more data, and an OutputStream has no more data when the sender determines it has nothing left to send.  The receiver doesn’t decide that;  the sender decides it.

Comment: You can use this function to determine if you can still write to an OutputStream: `return true`.  This may look like a silly function, but it is correct.

Comment: Like others have said: write and check for an exception. `ByteArrayOutputStream` lets you write until you're out of memory, and then throws a `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`. A network output stream may have a buffer and may block until the network is ready to send the next packet. If you write your own buffer or byte array based stream you could manage the buffer and block when it's full (probably expected), or throw when the buffer is full. Guess it depends on your actual use case.